# Android - Create SwipeViews inside another SwipeView

Tags: android, swipe

[image]
I need to create nested swipe views, for example like in the Facebook android application.
Any help is appreciated as I am a newbie.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: i just know to create simple swipe views... and i have just created them... have no idea to create tabs within them

Comment: please refer to the image i added.....

Answer (score 0):

Below are the link to get you started...

[Android Swipe Views](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html)

[Example Swipe Views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)